# Backbone.js: How to get the index of a model in a Backbone Collection?

Tags: backbone.js

Is there a way to find the index of a model within a collection?

Let's say in a view we have a model we're working on, could that model spit out it's index within the collection it's currently inside of? I'd like to do this because I want to access the model above or below the current target.

In other words is there something like:

```
index = this.model.index
modelAbove = this.collection.at( index-1 )
```

My data is a nested set so I can just do a search on the "lft" or "rgt" columns, but I didn't want to reinvent the wheel if Backbone already has this info available.

Answer (score 202, accepted):

yes, backbone provides access to many underscore.js methods on models and collections, including an `indexOf` method on collections. it also provides an `at` method like you've shown.

```
var index = this.collection.indexOf(this.model);
var modelAbove = this.collection.at(index-1);
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up! You know, it would be _so great_ if the `.collection` member was explicitly listed in the docs for `Model`...

Comment: I can't get this to work during an `initialize` call. Any idea how I could make that work?

Comment: This through me for a loop too. 'indexOf' is placed under Collections > Underscore Methods in the left hand menu, so it's not out in plain sight.

Comment: @Jeffpowrs It's also strange, because indexOf, in the underscore documentation, is an array function, whereas another array function, findIndex, doesn't work with collections.