# Backbone/Underscore: How to get index of a model inside render?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am new to backbone and underscore and I am trying to get model index on render to do some naming inside the template. 
This post helps find the index on events , 
[Backbone.js: How to get the index of a model in a Backbone Collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472055/backbone-js-how-to-get-the-index-of-a-model-in-a-backbone-collection)

but how can I find model index on render or initialize ?

```
  var SectionView = builder.classes.ItemView.extend({

    template: _.template(
        '<div class="pb-item-type-column pb-item custom-section">' +
            '<div class="panel fw-row">' +
                '<div class="panel-left fw-col-xs-6">' +
                    '<div class="column-title">Grid <%- item_index %></div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="panel-right fw-col-xs-6">' +
                    '<div class="controls">' +
                        '<i class="dashicons dashicons-edit edit-section-options"></i>' +
                        '<i class="dashicons dashicons-admin-page custom-section-clone"></i>' +
                        '<i class="dashicons dashicons-no custom-section-delete"></i>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="builder-items"></div>' +
        '</div>'
    ),
     events: {
        'click': 'onSectionWrapperClick',
        'click .edit-section-options': 'openSectionEdit',
        'click .custom-section-clone': 'cloneItem',
        'click .custom-section-delete': 'removeItem',
     },
     initialize: function() {
        this.defaultInitialize();

     },
     render: function() {
        this.defaultRender({

           item_index: 'this is where I need the index'
        });

     },

     cloneItem: function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();

        var index = this.model.collection.indexOf(this.model),
           attributes = this.model.toJSON(),
           _items = attributes['_items'],
           clonedSection;

        delete attributes['_items'];

        clonedSection = new Section(attributes);
        this.model.collection.add(clonedSection, {
           at: index + 1
        });
        clonedSection.get('_items').reset(_items);

     },

     openSectionEdit: function() {
        this.modal.open();
     },
     removeItem: function() {
        this.remove();

        this.model.collection.remove(this.model);
     },

  });

  var Section = builder.classes.Item.extend({

     defaults: function() {
        var defaults = _.clone(localized.defaults);

        defaults.shortcode = fwThzSectionBuilder.uniqueShortcode(defaults.type + '_');

        return defaults;
     },
     initialize: function() {
        this.defaultInitialize();

        /**
         * get options from wp_localize_script() variable
         */
        this.modalOptions = localized.options;

        this.view = new SectionView({
           id: 'fw-builder-item-' + this.cid,
           model: this
        });

     },

     allowIncomingType: function(type) {
        if (type == 'columns') {
           return true;
        } else {
           return false;
        }
     }

  });
```

If I could ad least get the parent on render it would help me further but this does not work either

```
$(this.el).parent();
```

I am extending this https://github.com/ThemeFuse/Unyson-Builder-Extension/blob/master/includes/option-types/builder/static/js/builder.js

**UPDATE AND SOLUTION :**

Since this was not my app and I was extending an existing one it was very hard to find my problem. My issue was that app creator has initiated a timeout  on initialize and render

https://github.com/ThemeFuse/Unyson-Builder-Extension/blob/master/includes/option-types/builder/static/js/builder.js#L348-L350

thus I was early on collection search.

Morslamina  answer and referenced post were both right.

So to you who is looking for index , give your index search some timeout and check. Collection must be there.

Comment: And `this.model.get('id')` doesn't work?

Comment: @StephenThomas, id works , but the collection is what I need and it is not available.  I think that they did not bound (this) in initialize in that app. 

at (stupid down voting troll) , why would you down vote a perfectly valid question and not even collaborate?

Comment: @StephenThomas,  nope , this.model.get('id') does not work either , 

I "see" the model but cant get anything inside of it except cid, looks like they did some resets in render https://github.com/ThemeFuse/Unyson-Builder-Extension/blob/master/includes/option-types/builder/static/js/builder.js#L708

I cant reach this http://prntscr.com/72gmpc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every model that has been assigned to a collection should have an attribute `this.collection` which references the parent collection. From there, it should be trivial to get the model's index.

```
render: function(){
    index = this.model.collection.indexOf(this.model)
}
```

Note that this might get a bit more complicated if you've added your model to multiple collections. In that case, you'll need a reference to the specific collection that you want the index of, because Backbone won't know automagically which collection you're talking about.

**EDIT:** After looking more closely at your code, I think you have a scoping issue. If you are literally calling

```
this.defaultRender({
   item_index: this.model.collection.indexOf(this.model)
});
```

Then `this` is scoped to your object that you pass to defaultRender, not to the view.

Try instead

```
index = this.model.collection.indexOf(this.model)
this.defaultRender({
   item_index: index
});
```

Comment: I tried that already and referenced the post that suggested the same snippet.  and yes model is used in multiple collections but I cant seem to be able to find the right way to index it

Comment: If your model is used in multiple collections, you'll have to pass your view a reference to the collection you want the index of, since `this.model.collection` won't necessarily hold the right reference.

Comment: do you mind showing an example , I posted both extends that I have.

Comment: The reference will have to come from wherever you instantize your collection, and I'm not sure that I see where you have done that in the code above. It will probably be in your main app file. I'm happy to help more, but I am confused by what your code is supposed to do and where it is supposed to do it.

Comment: Also, if `this.model.collection` is working in your `cloneItem` function it should work equally well in your `render` function.

Comment: I was also under that impression that if clone works it should work in render , but the app maker might have done something I don see in that defaultrender   https://github.com/ThemeFuse/Unyson-Builder-Extension/blob/master/includes/option-types/builder/static/js/builder.js#L704-L780

this is not my app I am just trying to extend it

Comment: I tried that also , it just does not see collection in render , no matter if I use this , or scope it to self or what ever combo , the render and intialize do not see the collection . thnx for looking at this

Comment: Is it a sequencing issue? i.e. are you rendering the view before you add the model to the collection?

Comment: not sure , like said I am completely new to backbone and underscore , this is original code and I am just modifying it https://github.com/ThemeFuse/Unyson-Shortcodes-Extension/blob/master/shortcodes/section/includes/page-builder-section-item/static/js/scripts.js

Comment: Is your code throwing an error and breaking the execution?

Comment: no , it runs perfectly smooth ,http://screencast.com/t/5NuWDHssDnZN, and that should be grid 1 ,2, 3  thus the index search

Comment: not even a sec delay kills everything , https://github.com/ThemeFuse/Unyson-Builder-Extension/blob/master/includes/option-types/builder/static/js/builder.js#L350

thnx!